# Netbeans on Ubuntu not saving panel locations

Tags: java, netbeans, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

Whenever I fire up netbeans on ubuntu the locations of the panels from my last session is not saved, unlike the behavior on windows.

I installed netbeans using OS independent package not through the package manager, and placed the extracted folder to /opt/netbeans

Everything works ok, but for example the netbeans "Output" panel always appears next to my source files, if I drag it to the bottom it stays there until I close netbeans and re-open it again, it re-appears besides my source files. Same thing applies for any panel I try to change positions, it gets really annoying when debugging, as i get 3 or 4 panels besides my source files instead of them being docked nicely in the bottom.

Is there any config file i need to change in order to fix this?

Comment: I think this belongs on http://superuser.com.

Comment: Should programming IDE questions belong on a programming site? If it gets moved to superuser nobody is going to answer it

Comment: i was hoping programmers would know more about this. I will move it over to superuser.com , might have better luck over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

issue this command in your terminal and check .netbeans dir whether it has 0755 or not. make sure it has write permission.

here is the command: ls -al ~

Comment: hmm, not sure why i didn't bother check the permissions on this folder? but yes your trick worked :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But for me it wasn't enough to set permisions on .netbeans to 755.
When I checked **Netbeans IDE log**(in View>Ide log), I red a lot of errors with `Cannot rename file Windows2Local/Modes/.nbattrs`.

I'm running netbeans without sudo, so I had to set permission on this file to 777, and now netbeans can write to this file, but I think that this is not very safe solution. But panels locations is saving and Netbeans startup is without any error.

file `.nbattrs` is located in `~/.netbeans/8.0.2/config/Windows2Local/Modes`

*Ubuntu 14.04.02 and Netbeans 8.0.2*